# Get JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied error when embedding powerbi report. in .Net core 2.0 web app

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc, powerbi, asp.net-core-2.0

When embedded powerbi report in Asp.net core 2.0 MVC  page. I got "
Exception was thrown at line 1000, column 335 in https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.3936.157/scripts/reportembed.externals.bundle.min.js
0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access is denied.
.

The MVC page is like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-9" id="dashboardContainer" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $dashboardContainer = $('#dashboardContainer')
    var embedConfiguration = {
        type: 'report',
        id: "@ViewBag.Id",
        embedUrl: "@ViewBag.Url",
        accessToken: "@ViewBag.Token",
        settings: {
            filterPaneEnabled: true,
            navContentPaneEnabled: true
        }
    }
    var reportContainer = $('#dashboardContainer')[0];
    var dashboard = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, embedConfiguration)

</script>
```

Interesting enough, if I put this into a Asp.net MVC page, there is no Access is denied error. I was wondering if there is any different between asp.net core mvc page and regular asp.net mvc page.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you:
[JavaScript "Access is Denied" error - no iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144473/javascript-access-is-denied-error-no-iframes?rq=1)

Apparently there is a known issue with ASP.NET Core.
Power BI Embedded doesn't support ASP.NET Core
[powerbi embeded in .net core 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340409/powerbi-embeded-in-net-core-1-1?rq=1)